# Virtual directory between 2 web apps in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, virtual-directory

I've recently moved 2 ASP.NET applications (let's call them the "Engine" and "Consumer") hosted on a VM with IIS to Azure web apps. Prior to the move, the Consumer site had a virtual directory with the path pointing to one of the Engine's subfolders (where images and PDFs reside). That allowed the Engine to share those files with the Consumer site, and I could host similar consumer sites that had access to the files as well.

Now that the 2 sites are on Azure as web apps, how can I have the Consumer web app "access" the Engine web app's subdirectory?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned both the apps are on same web app service. So, you can use 'Path Mapping' feature of app service.
App Service -> Configuration -> Path Mapping

Hopefully this hint will help.